# Coffeescript help to simplify if clause

Tags: coffeescript

I have this part of code in Coffee Script, and i can't figure out how it could be simplified with ternary if or something like this..

```
if options.tracks?
  @collection.add(options.tracks, {at: length+1, dest:options.dest})
else
  @collection.add(options, {at: length+1, dest:options.dest})
```

Sorry for stupid question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript has no easy tenary operator but you can use the if which will yield the last expression of either branch

```
@collection.add((if options.tracks then options.tracks else options), 
  {at: length+1, dest:options.dest})
```

Having said that. I wouldnt write it that way because imo its to much visual noise and hard to read. better do

```
tracks = if options.tracks then options.tracks else options
@collection.add(tracks, {at: length+1, dest:options.dest})
```

or even better

```
tracks = options.tracks || options
@collection.add(tracks, {at: length+1, dest:options.dest})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) will yield the same behaviour as you code:

```
@collection.add(options.tracks ? options, {at: length + 1, dest: options.dest})
```

I'd personally get rid of some the parens/braces and maybe use a separate variable for the first paramter... but this is more about personal preference really:

```
tracks = options.tracks ? options
@collection.add tracks, at: length + 1, dest: options.dest
```